# What test to use to find the probability of highest value?

Tags: machine-learning, normal-distribution, monte-carlo, online-algorithms

If I have a vector of around 40 values each with a normally distributed error, is there an easy way to figure out the probability of each element being the element with maximal true value? For context, this is coming from an idea to combine a min-max search with monte-carlo-tree search for use in the Leela Chess project.The idea would be to replace the average of nodes used in a plain mcts with a weighted average where the weights are the probability a given move is the best one.

It is probably worth noting that the method I need does not need to be accurate (within 1% should be fine), but needs to be very efficient as it will be run up to 100,000x per second. Bonus points for methods that can be updated on the fly, as that will make it much faster for the application.

Comment: Do you know the distribution of the error? The standard deviation of the error will have a significant influence. Suppose we have values a=0 and b=1. And we have standard deviation of 0.1 for both. The probability of b would be indistinguishable from 100%. If standard deviation is 100 then the probability will be about 50-50.

Comment: The error is normally distributed, and I can get good estimates of it in 2 different ways, and explaining how either works would be complicated, and is probably off topic anyway

Comment: You can use this answer https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24693/probability-that-random-variable-b-is-greater-than-random-variable-a to calculate probabilities pairwise. The final probability should be a multiplication of all the pairwise probabilities because P(AB)=P(A)P(B) if the values are independent.

Comment: thanks. Any chance there is a less computationally expensive way of doing this? The target usage is in a tree search where this will be run on length ~40 vectors at up to 100k times per second. I'm not sure this will be efficient enough as each time it's run would require 800 tests.

Comment: As discussed here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44139/what-is-px-1x-2-x-1x-3-x-1x-n?lq=1 you can do Monte-Carlo simulations where you generate random variables according to their distribution and then find the maximum. For n=20 it was faster even to calculate the probability of only one variable.

Comment: If you made that an answer, I'd accept it. Since I want to get the probability for each random variable, I suspect this will be faster as I can do it all with one mcts run.

Comment: The probability *must* depend on the prior probability distribution you assign to each of the values.  Without the prior there will be no unique solution.

Comment: of course, did I imply otherwise?

Comment: Yes: where you asked in your title for a "test," that suggested you might have a frequentist hypothesis test in mind.  Because you made no explicit references to a prior or to a Bayesian approach, it was only reasonable to be concerned that you might be asking a question that required assumptions you hadn't thought of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Theoretical formula**

According to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24693/probability-that-random-variable-b-is-greater-than-random-variable-a) calculating probabilities for two variables is simple:

$$P(A<B) = \Phi\left(\dfrac{\mu_B-\mu_A}{\sqrt{\sigma_A^2+\sigma_B^2}}\right)$$

If we look at the other [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44139/what-is-px-1x-2-x-1x-3-x-1x-n?lq=1) you will see a much more complicated formula for multiple variables (and it means that the maximum of variables are interdependent).
$$P(X_1 > \max X_i)  
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\prod_{i=2}^n \Phi\left(\frac{\alpha-\mu_i}{\sigma_i}\right)
\frac{1}{\sigma}\phi\left(\frac{\alpha-\mu_1}{\sigma_1}\right)\,\mathrm d\alpha$$
Taking into account that $\Phi$ is itself an integral without a theoretical solutions we have a very complicated formula with n integrals in it.

**Computational benchmarks**

As proposed in the second [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44139/what-is-px-1x-2-x-1x-3-x-1x-n?lq=1) the probabilities could be calculated using Monte-Carlo simulations.

Here are the benchmarks for integration of the theoretical formula, Monte-Carlo simulations and Ben's numerical calculation. All in Python:

```
Number of variables = 100.  
Monte-Carlo simulations: 531 ms (100000 simulations) (gives correct answer)
Numerical calculation from Ben's answer: 22.1s (gives correct answer)  
Integration according to the theoretical formula: 23.3s (gives wrong answer)
```

All algorithms are adjusted to have precision of around 1e-3 for the last value (99)

With the first approach I got the sum of probabilities equal to 0.92. Either it is a problem with integration in Python or the theoretical formula is wrong. And I was not able to vectorize the code so it should be significantly slower than C. With simulations I was able to write vector functions in `numpy` so the time should be closer to C.

The accuracy of the simulation is calculated with standard deviations (for values 99,98 and 97 respectively):

```
mean probability = 7.2469e-01, std=1.13458614e-03
mean probability = 2.2255e-01, std=7.49851686e-04
mean probability = 4.6310e-02, std=1.07472256e-03
...
```

It may be possible to calculate the theoretical formula faster than the simulation by some good approximation of the integration. For example remove all variables that are 3 standard deviations from the maximum value, use piece-wise linear function for $\Phi$, and use few evaluations for numerical computation of the integral.

**The code:**

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
from scipy.integrate import quad

n=100
m = np.arange(100.)
sd = np.ones(100)

def func(x,m,sd,i):
    mul = 1/sd[i]*norm.pdf((x-m[i])/sd[i])
    for j in range(n):
        if i!=j:
            mul = mul*norm.cdf((x-m[j])/np.sqrt(sd[i]**2+sd[j]**2))
    return mul
```

Measuring execution time of the theoretical integration formula in jupyter:

```
%%time
prob = np.array([quad(func,-np.inf,m[i],args=(m,sd,i),epsabs=1e-3)[0]+quad(func,m[i],np.inf,args=(m,sd,i),epsabs=1e-3)[0] for i in range(n)])
# 23.3 s
```

Measuring execution time of the Monte-Carlo simulations in jupyter:

```
%%time
nn=100000
a = np.random.normal(size=(n,nn))*sd[:,None]+m[:,None]
print((a==a.max(axis=0)).sum(axis=1)/nn)
# 531 ms
```

Calculating standard deviations:

```
nn=100000
a = np.random.normal(size=(n,nn,7))*sd[:,None,None]+m[:,None,None]
((a==a.max(axis=0)).sum(axis=1)/nn).std(axis=1)
```

Ben's numerical approach in R gives the same result as Monte-Carlo simulations. Here is the same code in Python that I used for benchmarking:

```
%%time
nn=25000
e_vec = np.random.normal(size=nn)
a = np.empty((n,nn))
i_range = np.arange(n)
for i in range(n):
    a[i]=np.prod(norm.cdf(m[i]-m[np.arange(len(m))!=i][:,None]+e_vec[None,:]), axis=0)
print(a.mean(axis=1))
#22.1s
```

Probabilities for values 99,98,97:

```
0.727, 0.225, 0.047
```

Code to calculate the standard deviation of Ben's numerical answer:

```
nn=25000
a4std = np.empty((7,n))
for ii in range(7):
    e_vec = np.random.normal(size=nn)
    a = np.empty((n,nn))
    i_range = np.arange(n)
    for i in range(n):
        a[i]=np.prod(norm.cdf(m[i]-m[np.arange(len(m))!=i][:,None]+e_vec[None,:]), axis=0)
    a4std[ii] = a.mean(axis=1)        
print(a4std.std(axis=0))
```

Standard deviation for values 99,98,97:

```
1.84e-3, 1.77e-3, 9.9e-4
```

Comment: you are giving the mcts version a fairly big advantage by forcing the integration to be accurate to 1 part in 10^9, while the monte carlo search has much higher error

Comment: @OscarSmith You are right. I updated the precision of the integration to 1e-3. The time is almost the same. 22s instead of 27s.

Comment: with a bit more work here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/206105/speed-up-weighted-average-for-leela-chess-zero I've gotten the time down even further. My laptop can do 1000 iterations for all values of a 40 item vector in 8.9 seconds.

Comment: Numba should decrease speed even further

Comment: not enough. I need this to be almost 1000 times faster to be useful.

Answer (score 1):

This problem gives a formula for the desired probability, but it is a complicated formula involving integration, that requires some kind of numerical evaluation.  Let $\mathbf{x} = (x_1,...,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a vector of values and let $\boldsymbol{\varepsilon} = (\varepsilon_1,...,\varepsilon_n) \sim \text{IID N}(0, \sigma^2)$ be a corresponding vector of errors that are added to the values.  The maximum of the error-inclusive values is denoted as:

$$M \equiv \max (x_1+\varepsilon_1,...,x_n+\varepsilon_n).$$

Let $\Phi$ and $\phi$ denote the CDF and PDF for the standard normal distribution.  The probability that the $k$th element of the error-inclusive values achieves the maximum value can be written as:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
p_k 
&\equiv \mathbb{P}(x_k+\varepsilon_k = M) \\[6pt]
&= \int \limits_{-\infty}^\infty \mathbb{P}(x_k+\sigma e = M | \varepsilon_k= \sigma e) \phi(e) de \\[6pt]
&= \int \limits_{-\infty}^\infty \Big( \prod_{i \neq k} \mathbb{P}(x_i + \varepsilon_i < x_k + \sigma e) \Big) \phi(e) de \\[6pt]
&= \int \limits_{-\infty}^\infty \Big( \prod_{i \neq k} \Phi \Big( \frac{x_k-x_i}{\sigma} + e \Big) \Big) \phi(e) de. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

This is a one-dimensional integral using well-known functions (the CDF and PDF of the normal distribution) that are programming into most statistical programming packages.  The integral does not have a closed-form solution, so you are going to need to use some kind of numerical method to approximate its value, and that is going to raise computational issues.  It is relatively simple to generate an estimate of this integral via [importance sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Importance_sampling):

$$p_k \approx \frac{1}{M} \sum_{\ell=1}^M \prod_{i \neq k} \Phi \Big( \frac{x_k-x_i}{\sigma} + e_\ell \Big) \quad \quad \quad e_1,...,e_M \sim \text{IID N}(0,1).$$

As an example, I will show you how to estimate these probabilities in `R` using the importance sampling approximation.  Using ten randomly generated starting points I get probabilities shown in the plot below.  (The black points show the ten $x_i$ values and the red bars show their respective probability of being the highest element once we add an error term.

[image]

---

**R code:** This is the `R` code to create a vectorised function that estimates the probabilities for each element via importance sampling with $W$ iterations, and then norms this probability vector to sum to one.  For large $W$ this should give you a reasonable approximation to the true probabilities.  This code includes the function and the plot code:

```
#Create vectorised function to estimate probabilities
ESTIMATE_PROBS <- function(x, sigma = 1, W = 10^6) {
    EEE   <- rnorm(W,0,1);
    K     <- length(x);
    PROBS <- rep(0,K);
    for (k in 1:k) { 
        PPP <- rep(0,W);
        for (w in 1:W) { PPP[w] <- prod(pnorm((x[k]-x[-k])/sigma + EEE[w], 0, 1)); }
        PROBS[k] <- mean(PPP); }
    PROBS/sum(PROBS); }

#Generate vector of values for testing
#For simplicity I will generate ten normally distributed values
set.seed(1);
x <- rnorm(10, 20, 5);

#Estimate probabilities for these values (sigma = 6, W = 10^6)
sigma <- 6;
W     <- 10^6;
EST <- ESTIMATE_PROBS(x, sigma, W);

#Plot the values and probabilities
library(ggplot2);
library(gridExtra);

PLOTDATA <- data.frame(Point = 1:10, Value = x, Probability = EST);
FIG1     <- ggplot(data = PLOTDATA, aes(x = Point, y = Probability)) +
            geom_bar(stat = 'identity', fill = 'red') + expand_limits(y = 1) +
            theme(axis.text.x   = element_blank(),
                  axis.ticks.x  = element_blank(),
                  plot.title    = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
                  plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
            ggtitle('Probability of being highest element') + 
            labs(subtitle = '(with additive error)') +
            xlab(NULL) + ylab('Probability');
FIG2     <- ggplot(data = PLOTDATA, aes(x = Point, y = Value)) +
            geom_point(size = 2) + expand_limits(y = c(10,30)) + 
            scale_y_continuous(position = 'right') +
            theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
                  axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) +
            xlab(NULL);

aligned_plots <- align_plots(FIG1, FIG2, align = 'hv', axis = 'tblr');
ggdraw(aligned_plots[[1]]) + draw_plot(aligned_plots[[2]]);
```

Comment: The equation you have written does not match the equation in my answer.  For a higher value $x_k$ the part $\tfrac{x_k-x_i}{\sigma}$ should be higher, which would give a higher value for the product of CDFs in the integrand.  This should lead to a higher integral probability for higher underlying values.  This is confirmed by the example I have coded in ```R```.

Comment: If you are getting a result where the highest probability is ascribed to the lowest value, I suspect you are probably multiplying the CDF over the wrong index.  In the equation I give in my answer, the product is over the index $i$, not the index $k$.  It might be worth double-checking if you have done that part correctly.

Comment: Your numerical calculation is the same as Monte-Carlo. I updated my answer and included a benchmark of your code translated into Python. I still could not integrate your analytical formula and get good results. On what theory is your numerical calculation based?

Comment: I used [importance sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Importance_sampling) to approximate the integral in my answer, using a series of values $E_i \sim \text{IID N}(0,1)$.

Comment: I have updated the post to show the formula for importance sampling.

Comment: I managed to calculate your integral. I still get a bit wrong results. Probability of value 99 61% instead of 72% for Monte-Carlo. It seems that I generally have problems integrating with Python.